# R: how to visualize longitudinal trajectory

Tags: r, visualization

I have a data set with 4 variables. It looks something like this:

```
ID    Month   X    Y
1     0       1.2  2.2
1     6       1.1  2.2
1     12      1.3  2.3
1     24      1.5  2.5
2     0       1.1  1.9
2     6       1.0  2.0
.     .       .    . 
.     .       .    .
.     .       .    .
```

I'm trying to see how X and Y change over time (Month). I did a basic scatter plot of my data
[image]

[image]

I can repeat this for all the different months, but I think this way of visualizing is not very informative. I'm interested in seeing how the data changes over time. One idea is to look at the migration path of the dots. I wanted to maybe divide up the graph into little squares and then shade in the squares given how many dots are in that square. So perhaps something like a lattice. Overall I just want to see how the dots "move" on the lattice over time. What is the best way to visualize this? My end goal is to see what's the probability that one dot moves to the next place on the lattice, but that's probably going to come in way later. For now I just want to visualize how the dots "move". Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you want to insert the "Month as a factor" info in the plot, perhaps you could manipulate appropriately something like `plot(DF[c("X", "Y")], col = rainbow(nlevels(factor(DF$Month)))[factor(DF$Month)])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the ID is your grouping variable, and the month is the ordering variable. So you want to plot for each group, ordered y versus x. I would use lattice library, though you can use ggplot2 as well.

A minimal example with lattice library:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                month=c(0, 6, 12, 24, 0, 6, 12, 24), 
                x=c(1.2, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5),
                y=c(2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.0, 2.7, 3.0))
df

  id month   x   y
1  1     0 1.2 2.2
2  1     6 1.1 2.2
3  1    12 1.3 2.3
4  1    24 1.5 2.5
5  2     0 1.1 1.9
6  2     6 1.0 2.0
7  2    12 1.2 2.7
8  2    24 1.5 3.0

library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x, group=id, data=df, type="b")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have close to 200 IDs? Wouldn't that clutter up my plot? Also I think the changes are going to be quite small, so I think most of my points will be cluttered in one region of my graph. How can I go about this?